# Check if 2D sub-array is ordered - Pyhthon JAX

Tags: python, arrays, permutation, jax

Let us suppose that we have an array `ordered`. We want to check if the sub-arrays `t` and  `t_inv` are following the same order as the imposed order in`order` array.

Reading from left to right: the first element is `[0,0]` and so on until `[0,3]`.
`t_inv` is inversed because the first to elements are swapped, they do not follow the ordering as in `ordered`.

```
# imposed order 
ordered = jnp.array([[0, 0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]])

# array with permuted order
t = jnp.array([[[0, 0],[0, 1], [0,3]]])
t_inv = jnp.array([[[0, 1],[0, 0], [0,3]]])
```

I expect the following:

```
 result: ordered(t) = 1, because "ordered"  
and ordered(t_inv) = -1, because "swapped/not ordered"
```

How can you check that the sub arrays are indeed part of the ordered array and ouput whether the order is correct or not?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the problem setup. How exactly does the `ordered` array relate to `t` and `t_inv`? When you say "the first elements are swapped", which elements of `t_inv` are you talking about, and how do they relate to what is specified in `ordered`? Is it important that `t` and `t_inv` are three-dimensional arrays, or is that a typo?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment. Let us assume ordered = [e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4], we define the order where element e_1 lies in the first position, element e_2 in second etc. 
Then we are given an array t = [e_1, e_2, e_4] which is respecting the order (e_1 is before e_2 and before e_4) , and t_inv = [e_2, e_1, e_4] has e_2 and e_1 in swapped positions (wrt to ordered=[...] array)
t and t_inv don't need to have the same number of elements.. we focus on the order (if e_1 is present, then it has to be always in the first position, then comes e_2 and so on)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was confused because before you edited the question, `t` and `t_inv` included pairs that didn't appear in `ordered`. But `t` and `t_inv` are still three-dimensional – is that your intention?

Comment: Yes, sorry I corrected the typo:  ``t`` and ``t_inv`` need to be a sub-array of ``ordered``. they don't necessarily need to have the same number of elements as ``ordered``, but definitely their elements need to be contained in ``ordered``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp

# imposed order 
ordered = jnp.array([[0, 0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]])

# array with permuted order
t = jnp.array([[0, 0],[0, 1], [0,3]])
t_inv = jnp.array([[0, 1],[0, 0], [0,3]])


def is_sorted(t, ordered):
  index = jnp.where((t[:, None] == ordered).all(-1))[1]
  return jnp.where((index == jnp.sort(index)).all(), 1, -1)

print(is_sorted(t, ordered))
# 1
print(is_sorted(t_inv, ordered))
# -1
```

Scaling-wise, it might be faster to use a solution based on `searchsorted`, but the current implementation of `jnp.searchsorted` in JAX is relatively slow because XLA doesn't have any native binary search algorithm, so in practice the full pairwise comparison can often be more performant.

Comment: thank you! I will also take a look at the ``jnp.searchsorted`` function

Comment: Wha if I the permuted order is e.g. ``c = jnp.array([[[0, 0],[0, 1], [0,1]], [[0, 1],[0, 0], [0,3]]])`` , I concatenated ``t`` and ``t_inv``. 
I tried using jax vmap over the inputs and replacing ``t[:, None] == ordered`` with ``t == ordered``, however I get a ``ConcretizationTypeError:``

Comment: You would only get a `ConcretizationTypeError` if you attempted to do control flow using `t == ordered` within a transform like `jit` or `vmap`, or tried to pass it to a NumPy (not `jax.numpy`) function. I suspect your description here leaves out some changes you may have made.

Comment: yes, I am also using ``jax.vmap(is_sorted, in_axes=(0,None))(c, ordered)``